# Roaraudio fails to install

Tags: 18.04, sound, error-handling

I have been trying to install roaraudio yet I keep facing these errors:

```
Setting up roaraudio (1.0~beta12-2+b1) ...
Job for roaraudio.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status roaraudio.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript roaraudio, action "start" failed.
● roaraudio.service - LSB: sound server for audio mixing
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/roaraudio; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-09-25 03:32:00 EET; 4ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 11063 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/roaraudio start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx roaraudio[11063]: Cannot connect to server request channel
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx roaraudio[11063]: jack server is not running or cannot be started
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx roaraudio[11063]: JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx roard[11073]: (roard: driver_ao.c:52): Warning: The libao driver is obsolete, use another!
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx systemd[1]: roaraudio.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx roard[11073]: (roard: driver_ao.c:127): Error: Can not open audio device via libao.
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: sound server for audio mixing.
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx roard[11073]: (roard: output.c:454): Error: add_output(drv='ao', dev='(null)', opts='sync'): can not open output driver.
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx roard[11073]: (roard: roard.c:768): Error: Can not open listen socket: Socket already in use
Sep 25 03:32:00 Omar-HP-Laptop-15-da1xxx roard[11073]: (roard: roard.c:2416): Error: Can not open listen socket!
dpkg: error processing package roaraudio (--install):
 installed roaraudio package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 roaraudio
```

So, any help ?!!

Thanks in advance for the reply

Comment: Your output shows no less than five fatal errors (by my count). Do you understand what those error messages mean? You seem to be using a version of the package that does not appear to be from the Ubuntu repositories ...why? Does your audio NEED to be 'roaraudio', or are you open to alternatives?

Comment: @user535733 unfortunately I'm working on a project that requires roaraudio

Comment: Where did you get this version? `apt-cache policy roaraudio` and `lsb_release -a` please edit your question for output.